# What is standard approach to experiment with two python libraries defined in two github repositories?

Tags: python, git, github, pip, virtualenv

I want to experiment two libraries available on github. These libraries provide setup.py files. Usually I used pipenv. So to install libraries from github, I usually did:

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/org/repo.git#egg=lib-name
```

But this installs the library inside virtual environment's lib folder like `/home/user-name/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv-name/lib`. How should I get those libraries not installed in this lib folder but available in my workspace where I can make required changes to both of them and use in some py file? I was thinking to simply clone both of them in my current workspace. But cloning them will not install their dependency. How can I install their dependencies without installing them in lib folder. Will doing `pipenv install .` invoke their setup.py and install only their dependencies and not themselves?

Also one more concern: I guess simply checking out repository wont make it usable in my py file. Say if I have following structure after checking out two libraries and creating py file (and I have manually installed all of dependencies of both repositories):

```
my_worksace
|
|__ repo1
|     |
|     |__ lib1 
|
|__ repo2
|     |
|     |__ lib2
|
|__ mypyfile1.py
|
|__ mymodule
      |
      |__ mypyfile2.py
```

Then, I cannot use modules from `lib1` and `lib2` directly in `mypyfile1.py`, right?

**Update**

I tried moving `lib1` and `lib2` outside, that is inside `my_workspace` folder directly:

```
my_worksace
|
|__ repo1 (unused)
|
|__ lib1 (cut pasted from inside repo2)
|
|__ repo2 (unused)
|
|__ lib2 (cut pasted from inside repo2)
|
|__ mypyfile1.py
|
|__ mymodule
      |
      |__ mypyfile2.py
```

and now am able to use them inside `mypyfile1.py`, but not inside `mypyfile2.py`

Comment: If you make changes to the libraries. `pip install` from the modified versions on your local hard disk, or push to your own Github and install from there. You seem to mix a nontrivial number of questions which each should have obvious solutions and trivial duplicates.

Comment: Ohhh so I should fork, branch and then clone these repos separately, make changes to them, commit, push them and then install them into my target venv where I am trying to use them in mypyfile? Thats the obvious standard approach (not mixing changes to repos and using them), right?

Comment: If I understand your question at all, that sounds like a reasonable approach, and reasonably standard.